# Not able to interact with my smart contract after deploying and even getting the contract address (locally on hardhat)

Tags: next.js, deployment, ethers.js, hardhat

[This is the code I have written in deploy.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXer.png)
[this is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZYnQ.png)

Below is my smart contract

pragma solidity >= 0.6.0;

//Here the contract will start
contract Voting{

```
//Struct function for the voter
struct Voter{
    bool isVote; //checker variable to determine whether the voter has voted before
    uint id; //ID of the voter        
    string towhom; //to whom the voter has voted
}

//Declaring and Initialising the variables for votes
uint bjp = 0;
uint congress = 0;
uint aap = 0;
uint nota = 0;

//Initializing the time variable to the time of deployment
uint time_inital = block.timestamp;
uint time_final;
//Setting total count of the variable to be zero
uint counter = 0;

//Declaring the static array to initialize the number of the vote
Voter[20] voters;

//Initializing the ids of the voter via construction during the deployment
constructor() {
    for (uint i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        voters[i].id = i+1000;
        voters[i].isVote = false;
        voters[i].towhom = "";
    }
    time_inital = block.timestamp;
}

//Modifiers

//Modifier used for comparing the current time and the
//time of the declaration of the result
modifier Time(){
    require(block.timestamp >= time_inital + 30 seconds);
    _;
}

//Modifier used for checking whether the voter is
//giving his vote again
modifier IsVote(uint i) {
    require(voters[i].isVote == false);
    _;
}

//Functions

//Function to increase the vote count of BJP
function BJP(uint i) public IsVote(i){
    bjp++; //bjp counter will increases by one
    counter++; //Total count will increase by one
    voters[i].isVote = true; //Made the voter ineligible to vote
    voters[i].towhom = "BJP"; //Keeps the record of the voter list to whom the voter has voted
}

function Congress(uint i) public IsVote(i){
    congress++;
    counter++; //Total count will increase by one
    voters[i].isVote = true; //Made the voter ineligible to vote
    voters[i].towhom = "Congress"; //Keeps the record of the voter list to whom the voter has voted       
}

function AAP(uint i) public IsVote(i){
    aap++;
    counter++; //Total count will increase by one
    voters[i].isVote = true; //Made the voter ineligible to vote
    voters[i].towhom = "AAP"; //Keeps the record of the voter list to whom the voter has voted    
}

function NOTA(uint i) public IsVote(i){
    nota++;
    counter++; //Total count will increase by one
    voters[i].isVote = true; //Made the voter ineligible to vote
    voters[i].towhom = "None of the above"; //Keeps the record of the voter list to whom the voter has voted      
}

//This function will return the votes of BJP
function VotesOfBJP() external view Time() returns(uint) {
    return bjp;
}

//This function will return the votes of Congress
function VotesOfCongress() external view Time() returns(uint) {
    return congress;
}

//This function will return the votes of AAP
function VotesOfAAP() external view Time() returns(uint) {
    return aap;
}

//This function will return the votes of None of the above
function VotesOfNOTA() external view Time() returns(uint) {
    return nota;
}

//This function finally declares the result of the all the candidates
//registered to be voted and the total voting of the elections
function Declaration() external view Time() returns(uint){
    return counter;
}
```

I am trying to access funcitons of my smart contracts while deploying it locally on the hardhat
but it is providing the above given error

Comment: instead of posting image, pls post the code itself.

Comment: Bro it is not fixing up the indentation requirement to post the problem I have tried it  the image link for the deploy file is also attached as well as the error, please help me to solve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.